# Directory traversal in vanilla Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to understand basic directory traversal. Nearly all the examples I have found utilize the `walkdir` or `glob` library, which I've had good success with. However, I'm trying to do this now with just the `std` lib.

There is a [primitive example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) in the standard lib docs listing the following function:

```rust
fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &dyn Fn(&PathBuf)) -> io::Result<()> {
    for e in read_dir(path)? {
        let e = e?;
        let path = e.path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            visit(&path, cb)?;
        } else if path.is_file() {
            cb(&path);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The part I'm confused about is how to access the `cb` function in the context of a closure. I'm having a hard time finding an example.

For instance, I want to do something basic like collect the resulting paths into a `Vec`. Obviously, this does not work:

```rust
fn main() {
    // create a new path
    let path = Path::new(PATH);
    let mut files = Vec::new();

    visit(path, |e| {
      files.push(e);
    });
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
expected reference `&dyn for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::path::PathBuf)`
     found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:24:17: 26:6 files:_]
```

So my question is, how can I return a `Fn` and process the result in a closure context?

Comment: If you pay attention to the *full* error message (which you did not include here) you will see a hint toward what you should do to resolve the error: `help: consider borrowing here: '&|e| files.push(e)'`. If you fix that, you will see that you have further errors that need resolving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, but the first one that you are getting the error message for is because `&dyn Fn(&PathBuf)` expects a *reference* to a function. You can resolve that error by following the suggestion from the error message: `help: consider borrowing here: '&|e| files.push(e)'`

That turns your call into:

```
visit(path, &|e| files.push(e));
```

However, this code is still incorrect and results in yet another error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `files` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> playground\src\main.rs:48:22
   |
48 |     visit(path, &|e| files.push(e));
   |                      ^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

This time, it's because you're mutating `files` inside a `Fn` (immutable closure). To fix that, you need to change your function type to `FnMut` (see [Closures As Input Parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/fn/closures/input_parameters.html) for more information):

```
fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &dyn FnMut(&PathBuf))
```

But you're still not done. There is now another error, but like the first, it comes with a suggestion for what needs to be changed:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*cb` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> playground\src\main.rs:39:13
   |
32 | fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &dyn FnMut(&PathBuf)) -> io::Result<()> {
   |                           -------------------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut dyn for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r std::path::PathBuf)`
...
39 |             cb(&path);
   |             ^^ `cb` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

In order for your closure to mutably borrow the data it uses, you also have to take a mutable reference to the closure itself, and you'll need to update your `visit()` call to match:

```
fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &mut dyn FnMut(&PathBuf))
...
visit(path, &mut |e| files.push(e));
```

Almost there, but there is one final error to resolve:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
  --> playground\src\main.rs:48:26
   |
47 |     let mut files = Vec::new();
   |         --------- `files` declared here, outside of the closure body
48 |     visit(path, &mut |e| files.push(e));
   |                       -  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `e` escapes the closure body here
   |                       |
   |                       `e` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
```

You've defined your closure to take a reference to a `PathBuf` (`&PathBuf`), but you're trying to push those references into a `Vec` that is outside of the closure, which won't work because those references will be invalid once the closure goes out of scope. Instead, you should use an owned value -- simply `PathBuf`. You'll also need to update your usage of the closure to pass the `PathBuf` instead of a reference:

```
fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &mut dyn FnMut(PathBuf))
...
cb(path);
```

It finally works! Here is what the full program looks like now. Note that you should also `unwrap()` your call to `visit()` since it returns a `Result`. I've also added a simple `for` loop to print out the file names.

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::fs::*;
use std::io;

fn visit(path: &Path, cb: &mut dyn FnMut(PathBuf)) -> io::Result<()> {
    for e in read_dir(path)? {
        let e = e?;
        let path = e.path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            visit(&path, cb)?;
        } else if path.is_file() {
            cb(path);
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("./your/path/here");
    let mut files = Vec::new();
    visit(path, &mut |e| files.push(e)).unwrap();
    for file in files {
        println!("{:?}", file);
    }
}
```